# how to get the values of a entire table having text and checkbox fields jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox, jstl

I have a `jsp` which iterates through a list printing the first name, last name and Paid (`Checkbox`). All these values come from oracle DB. Paid checkbox is editable (So, the user can check/uncheck the `checkbox`). I'm having a problem in getting all the updated values from `jsp` to `servlet`. I need to know how to get the entire list back in `servlet` with the `checkbox` updated values. Please let me know.

JSP Code snippet.

```
<c:forEach items="${nameList}" var="nameObj">  
  <tr>  
    <td><label>${nameObj.firstName}</label></td>  
    <td><label>${nameObj.lastName}</label></td>  
    <c:if test="${nameObj.paid}">  
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="paid" id="paid" checked ></td>  
  </c:if>  
  </tr>  
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this code as

```
  <c:forEach items="${nameList}" var="nameObj">  
       <tr>  
      `<td><label>`FirstName`</label><input type="text" name="firstName" value="${nameObj.firstName}"/></td>`  
      `<td><label>`LastName:`</label><input type="text" name="lastName" value="${nameObj.lastName}"/></td>`  

  <c:if test="${nameObj.paid}">  
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="paid" id="paid" checked /></td>  
    </c:if>  
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, how do I get the values of firstName, lastName and paid fields in servlet.

Comment: @Javauser try inside servlet String firstname=request.getParameter("firstName"); in same way you also get value of lastName and Checkbox field from jsp to servlet